# PHP web sockets - can't bind to host

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/

But, for love nor money, I couldn't get a response out of the console.

I loaded up the startDeamon manually and found it was failing to bind to my (local) host.

```
Warning: socket_bind() [function.socket-bind]: Host lookup failed [-10001]: Unknown host
```

My local server is running on http://localhost:33. I have specifying my host as both localhost and 127.0.0.1, with and without http, and with and without specifying the port, but no joy.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try passing the integer `0` as the interface argument to `socket_bind()` - this should bind to all available interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try using port 12345 instead of 33.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. Unfortunately it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

remove the http:// part and just try access it as localhost

Comment: Gave up on this long ago - tried this and other solutions, none of which solved the problem in my case. I later learned that setting up a socket server is non-trivial, so I used Pusher.com instead. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot use localhost, or 127.0.0.1 when dealing with sockets, but need to use the domain/host name or host IP address instead. It is explained as a user experience in the PHP5 manual section

Comment: I'm looking at [socket_bind()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php) and it uses localhost as an example and indicates it is valid. Could you link to the page that verifies your comment?